# How do I replace the html objects with it's text content?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace link parameters with the query strings and I'm a noob when it comes to web dev

I've tried String(), object.textContent() and some more things but can't seem to get what I want

here's my code:

```
link="https://someWebsite?phone=replace1&message=replace2"
link = link.replace("replace1",phone); //phone is an input box returned by document.getElementByID() method
link = link.replace("replace2",message); //message is a text area returned by document.getElementByID() method


expected link: https://someWebsite?phone=123456&mesaage=somemessage
actual link: https://someWebsite?phone= [object HTMLInputElement]&message=[object HTMLTextAreaElement]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) *"I've tried String(), object.textContent() and some more things"* **Show us** the code you've tried, exactly, with copy and paste. It's best to update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: (In particular, you were on the right track with `textContent` **if** the elements are not inputs; otherwise, you'd want `value`.)

Comment: It sounds like `phone` and `message` are `input` objects. Try `phone.value` and `message.value`.

Comment: T.J. SO needs a button so we can all add exactly your comment.

Comment: @AustinMullins Thank you! phone.value and message.value did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the *value* of an `input`, you use its `value`. Also, in query strings, you must encode query parameters with `encodeURIComponent`¹. So:

```
link="https://someWebsite?phone=replace1&message=replace2"
link = link.replace("replace1",encodeURIComponent(phone.value));
link = link.replace("replace2",encodeURIComponent(message.value));
```

Also note that each of those will replace the **first** occurrence, not all occurrences. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/) if you need to replace each of those (`replace1`, `replace2`) in more than just the first place it appears.

Of course, with the code you've shown, it would make more sense not to use `replace` at all:

```
link = "https://someWebsite?phone=" + encodeURIComponent(phone.value) +
       "&message=" + encodeURIComponent(message.value);
```

Or with ES2015+:

```
link = `https://someWebsite?phone=${encodeURIComponent(phone.value)}&message=${encodeURIComponent(message.value)}`;
```

---

¹ You have to encode the *names*, too, but `encodeURIComponent("phone")` is `"phone"` and `encodeURIComponent("message")` is `"message"`, so... But if you had other characters in there, such as `[]`, you'd need to encode them.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery we use backticks and ${} for string interpolation:

```
`some text ${replacedtext} some other text`
```

If you're using vanilla javascript use + signs for string interpolation:

```
"some text" + replacedtext + "some other text"
```

Hope this helps